# How can I insert array using ajax laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

Help please ,I recover my data in frontend use jquery and I can display in console, now I want to insert these data in the database we are using ajax and laravel, here is my table.

Hi,help please ,I recover my data in frontend use jquery :

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <th>Archive</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>matricule</th>
            <th>nom & prenom</th>
            <th>salaire net</th>
            <th>nbre de jour </th>
            <th>prime</th>
        </tr>
        @if($salaries->count())
            @foreach($salaries as $key => $salarie)
                <tr id="tr_{{$salarie->id}}">
                  <td>archive</td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="{{$salarie->id}}"></td>
                  <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                  <td class="mat">{{ $salarie->matricule }}</td>
                  <td class="name">{{ $salarie->nom }} {{ $salarie->prenom }}</td>
                  <td class="salaireValue">{{ $salarie->salairenet }}</td>
                  <td ><input type="text" name="nbreJ" class="form-control" value="{{$data['nbr']}}"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </table>
```

This is my code jquery which allows to recover my data

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
         if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
         {
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);  
         } else {  
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);  
         }  
        });
         $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
            if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
            }else{
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);
            }
         });

         //get value
         $('.add-all').on('click', function() {
           var allChecked = $('.checkbox:checked');
  for (var i = 0; i < allChecked.length; i++) {
    var currentHtml = $(allChecked[i]).parent().siblings('.salaireValue')[0];
    var currentHtml1 = $(allChecked[i]).parent().siblings('.name')[0];
    var currentHtml2 = $(allChecked[i]).parent().siblings('.mat')[0];
    var currentHtml3 = $(allChecked[i]).parent().siblings('.datea')[0];

      var result = parseInt($(currentHtml)[0].innerText);
      var result1 = $(currentHtml1)[0].innerText;
      var result2 = parseInt($(currentHtml2)[0].innerText);


    console.log(result);
    console.log(result1);
    console.log(result2);
  }

});  
    });
</script>
```

This my controller I do not know how to write the function.

```
 public function addMultiple(Request $request){

    dd(request());

            }
```

route

```
Route::post('mensuel', ['as'=>'salarie.multiple-add','uses'=>'SalarieController@addMultiple']);
```

Comment: Can you show your `dd($request->all())` from controller?

Comment: `dd()` wont work because its ajax so try  `logger()->info($request->all())`

Comment: not think ,empty

Comment: also not think ,because he has nothing to send to a controller